# Decorative ceiling junction box cover

Tags: junction-box, cover

I know the junction box cannot be permanently covered, but I am looking for ideas for decorative covers. we are taking down a stairwell light fixture and just want to cover it up with something other than the plain round plates.

Comment: Personally, I'd watch garage sales for a stuffed fish.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic (decorating advice).

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous approaches.

The simplest is paint. If a blank cover and its screws are painted to match the wall, the box will recede in appearance.

Similarly, if the wall is wallpapered, you can wrap the blank cover with paper, gluing down a slight margin of the paper to the underside of the cover. Paint the heads of screws a color close to the paper's tone.

You can buy [medallions or rosettes](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ekena-Millwork-5-7-8-in-x-7-8-in-x-5-7-8-in-Lyre-Rosette-ROS05X05LY/203798923) (meant for centers of ceilings) that can be glued to a blank cover.

[image: rosette]

If you search for *ceiling medallions*, you can find hundreds of styles, although many of them are pierced for electrical wires.

```
 Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```

Comment: Ceiling medallions would still need to allow removal of the cover.

Comment: @Harper Several approaches possible. Adhesives that allow easy on/off, like those used for dorm posters; small holes drilled through the medallion to allow affixing screws; velcro; double faced foam tape, new piece after each removal; etc.